# Swift Storyboard "Illegal Configuration"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

While my swift project was running, it suddenly started giving an error and is not being built. In the log records, there is an error called `Illegal Configuration` in `.storyboard` file, but when I go into my files, no error appears. I just get this error while building.

[image: Illegal Configuration error in storyboard]

Comment: Try cleaning your project.  Restart Xcode too.

Comment: @davejlin I tried but it doesn't work, when I delete all the photos and labels and add them again, it is fixed. But it's really annoying.

Comment: Does it happen frequently, or just a one time thing?

Comment: I've had it often before. When I delete the items in the storyboard and add them again, the problem is fixed. I couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: Unfortunately your screen shot shows a truncated version of the error message. Please try to capture the entire message, eg from the build report.

Comment: @matt file:///InstagramTest/InstagramTest/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: The postImage outlet from the FeedViewController to the UIImageView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Some things that haven't been mentioned - are you using multiple version of Xcode simultaneously? That's given me weirdness before. Is the .nib or storyboard very very old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in the storyboard you are trying to make an outlet from eg a view controller to eg a prototype cell in a table view or collection view. That is indeed illegal, as it is meaningless. Don't do that.

Comment: I do not know why Xcode alerts you to the issue only intermittently. It's just a quirk of the build process, I guess.

Comment: yes you are right, I created a prototype table but I was defining the codes in the wrong place :) thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. If you aren't clear on how to communicate with cells repeatedly generated from a prototype, feel free to ask a separate question about that. An outlet from outside the prototype cell is not the way! :)